# Building Webhook to send Recordings info from Zoom to Google App Script - Getting Status 302

Tags: google-apps-script, webhooks, http-status-code-302, zoom-sdk

I'm building a webhook that will send the completed recordings info from Zoom to a deployed Web App. Webhook will fire when the recording is completed.

Below is the complet schema of the event notification:

```html
{
  "event": "string",
  "payload": {
    "account_id": "string",
    "object": {
      "id": "integer",
      "uuid": "string",
      "host_id": "string",
      "topic": "string",
      "type": "integer",
      "start_time": "string",
      "timezone": "string",
      "host_email": "string",
      "duration": "integer",
      "share_url": "string",
      "total_size": "integer",
      "recording_count": "integer",
      "recording_files": [
        {
          "id": "string",
          "meeting_id": "string",
          "recording_start": "string",
          "recording_end": "string",
          "file_type": "string",
          "file_size": "number",
          "play_url": "string",
          "download_url": "string",
          "status": "string",
          "recording_type": "string"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This is my Web App code:

```js
function doGet(e) {
  return ContentService.createTextOutput('doGet request');
}

function doPost(e) {    
  try {
    var input = JSON.stringify(e.postData.contents);
    input = JSON.parse(input);
    //var myData = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
    //return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(myData);
  }
  catch (e) {
    throw new Error(e);
  }
  return ContentService.createTextOutput("doPost received");
}
```

The Web App is deployed with Execute the app as the owner and everyone has access to the app.

I'm getting Status 302 on Zoom side.

Please give me some advice on this. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does it matter? You already have the webhook info right?

Comment: @TheMaster I also think that in the OP's situation, the values has already been retrieved at Web Apps side. But when OP checks the log of webhook, the status code of `302` is shown. I thought that OP might want to modify `302` to `200`. For this, I proposed a modification point.

Comment: @Tanaike  Thank you for the input. Yes. I'm aware  of the redirection and I also thought the same about contentService(as written in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/content#redirects)). Wondering if zoom can be configured to follow redirects...

Comment: For example, in the case of the dialog of Slack, when `ContentService.createTextOutput` is not returned, an error occurs. So the response value is required to choose for each API. In this case, it is required to do try and error, while the document is checked. At zoom webhook, I think that `ContentService.createTextOutput` was not suitable. About this, I have to apologize to OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this modification?

#### Modification points:

At Web Apps, when `ContentService.createTextOutput` is returned, it seems that the redirect might be used. From the status code of `302` in your question, I thought that this might be the reason of your issue. So for example, in order to avoid this issue, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```
function doPost(e) {
  try {
    var input = JSON.stringify(e.postData.contents);
    input = JSON.parse(input);
    //var myData = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
    //return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(myData);
  }
  catch (e) {
    throw new Error(e);
  }
  // return ContentService.createTextOutput("doPost received"); // Removed
}
```

- **When you modified the script of Web Apps, please redeploy Web Apps as new version. By this, the latest script is reflected to Web Apps. Please be careful this.**

#### Note:

- If the status code was changed to `200` when no values are returned to the zoom side, in this case, I think that `HtmlService.createHtmlOutput` might be able to be also used.

Comment: Hi Tanaike, thanks for your input, but it's still getting status 302 after I made the modification as you suggested.

Comment: Hi Tanaike, the status is now 200 after I disabled the Webhook and activated it again. It should be good now. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @Anh Nguyen Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.